# C# UWP closing application multiple views

Tags: c#, uwp, multiple-views, application-close

I have a UWP app that dynamically creates another view. But, the problem is when I close the first window, the second still stays on.

With this code I am creating new view:

```
        CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
        int newViewId = 0;
        await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), null);
            Window.Current.Content = frame;
            // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
            Window.Current.Activate();

            newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        });
        bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
```

How to close the application when user close the first window?

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to [Show multiple views for an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/show-multiple-views).

> If secondary views are open, the main view’s window can be hidden – for example, by clicking the close (x) button in the window title bar - **but its thread remains active**. Calling Close on the main view’s Window causes an `InvalidOperationException` to occur. (Use [`Application.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Exit) to close your app.) If the main view’s thread is terminated, the app closes.

```
private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Exit();
}
```

> You could also choose if you want to close the initial window and remove it from the taskbar by specifying the value of [`ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions).So that there is a single view on your desktop. You just need to close it for closing the application.

```
 private int currentViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
 private async void ShowNewView()
 {
     CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
     int newViewId = 0;
     await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
     {
         Frame frame = new Frame();
         frame.Navigate(typeof(SecondPage), null);
         Window.Current.Content = frame;
         Window.Current.Activate();
         newViewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
     });

     await ApplicationViewSwitcher.SwitchAsync(newViewId, currentViewId, ApplicationViewSwitchingOptions.ConsolidateViews);
 }
```